# create key mapping file Bluestack on Mac(OSX)

Tags: android, macos, mobile, bluestacks

I want to do key mapping in Bluestack but seem like it not provide in OSX version. So, Is there any way to create key mapping file for an application and how to setting it?

Thank you

Comment: Hey.. have you found a solution for this problem so far? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Not yet supported

Bluestacks 3.0, which is available on the Windows platform, [supports key mapping](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003485046-Introducing-key-mapping-overlay-a-visual-guide).

As of timestamp of this answer, Bluestacks for MacOS is at version `2.0.1 (14)`, which currently does not support key mapping.

In August of 2017, Bluestacks officially said [that support for Bluestacks 3.0 is not yet in the pipeline for development](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/6s92kq/bluestacks_3_for_mac/) which means that MacOS users need to dual boot windows or use a Windows PC altogether.

### Alternative

1. Use a Windows PC
2. Dual boot your Mac with a Windows.